# How to prevent json modification while wix msi upgrading

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am new to wix msi .I am using Wix to create msi  for my window service .While installing msi, a json file will be created in installation folder with application details(using .net core). This file will be modified (recreating) while upgrading msi .I want to prevent json being modified on each msi upgrade.

I have tried couple of methods. But didn't get desired result.
1.Using custom action-

```
     <Property Id="C_TEMP" Value="C:\Temp" />
        <Property Id="ROBOCOPY_EXE">robocopy.exe</Property>
        <CustomAction Id="CopyToTemp" Property="ROBOCOPY_EXE" Return="ignore" ExeCommand='"[INSTALLDIR]\Configuration" "[C_TEMP]\ServerSettings" AgentDetails.json' />
        <CustomAction Id="CopyFromTemp" Property="ROBOCOPY_EXE" Return="ignore" ExeCommand='"[C_TEMP]\ServerSettings" "[INSTALLDIR]\Configuration" AgentDetails.json /MOVE /IS' />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="CopyToTemp" Before="InstallInitialize">Installed AND (NOT REMOVE="ALL" OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

2. using component

```
<Component Id="myconfig" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes" > 
          <File Id="AgentDetails.json" Name="AgentDetails.json"  KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\AgentDetails.json"  /> 
        </Component>
```

Comment: question needs clarification - how json will be created?

Comment: Only two possibilities. 1) It's coped 2) It's created via custom action.